# I want to upload two image files to two separate folders using codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, file-upload

in my html form i have two file input fields

```
<div style="width: 125px; height: 35px; float: left; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px;">
                    Image Large
                </div>
                <div style="width: 125px; height: 35px; float: left; margin-top: 15px;">
                    <input  type="file" name="large_image" id="large_image"/>
                </div>
                <div style="clear: both;"></div>

                <div style="width: 125px; height: 35px; float: left; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px;">
                    Image Small
                </div>
                <div style="width: 125px; height: 35px; float: left; margin-top: 15px;">
                    <input  type="file" name="small_image" id="small_image"/>
                </div>
```

in my controller file I have two functions to upload small and large image. this two functions are executed by one single function like

```
private function insert_products() {
$this->upload_prodct_img_small();
        $this->upload_prodct_img_large();
}
```

the two uploading functions are like this.

```
private function upload_prodct_img_large() {
        $image_name = $this->get_image_name_uploade();
        $config['upload_path'] = 'uploaded/large/';
        $config['file_name'] = $image_name;
        $config['overwrite'] = 'FALSE';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'png|PNG';
        //$config['max_size'] = '1000';
        //$config['max_width'] = '720';
        //$config['max_height'] = '960';
        $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('large_image')) {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', $error);
        } else {
            $error = 'Successfully Uploaded';
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', $error);
        }
    }

    private function upload_prodct_img_small() {
        $image_name_small = $this->get_image_name_uploade();
        $config['upload_path'] = 'uploaded/';
        $config['file_name'] = $image_name_small ;
        $config['overwrite'] = 'FALSE';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'png|PNG';
        //$config['max_size'] = '1000';
        //$config['max_width'] = '180';
        //$config['max_height'] = '240';
        $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('small_image')) {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', $error);
        } else {
            $error = 'Successfully Uploaded';
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', $error);
        }
    }
```

in both cases I rename the file in to a single file name in the $config array.

The problem is this. when I'm trying to upload both files only "small_image" is uploading and always the other one is missing.
you can see that i had commented out that width height and sizes . because if I didn't do that it is giving me an error saying "the file you uploaded is exceeding the allowed height or width" (something like that).
 I have double checked that file size i'm uploading is exactly same as the allowed.

and the other case is I did something like this.

```
 private function insert_products() {
    //$this->upload_prodct_img_small();
      $this->upload_prodct_img_large();
    }
```

then the large image is uploading without giving any error.

can't find what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: 10 Views still no reply :(

Comment: did you give premissions to large_image folder?

Comment: yes there is no errors in permissions. because when i try to upload only large image it is uploading without errors

Comment: Better upload only one file (large) and create small image in coding with use of large image.

Comment: still couldn't get any answers

Answer (score 3):

Just initialize the new configuration array before loading the upload library in the second function.

i.e. initialize $config by including the line :

```
$this->upload->initialize($config);
```

before the line :

```
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
```

in the *upload_prodct_img_small()* function.

In general, you always have to initialize a new configuration before using it with a  library, otherwise, the default configuration will be used. In your case, the default is your first configuration.

Comment: @Yasitha : hope you got your answer !

Answer (score 1):

Here is what i use, i tested it, and it works for me just read through the comments.

```
set_time_limit(0);
$config['upload_path'] = './assets/uploads/pictures';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'png';
$config['max_size'] = '1000';
$config['width']     = 188;
$config['height'] = 187;

//load library with first config
$this->load->library('upload', $config);

if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
{
    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
    $this->view_data['system_message'] = $this->_msg('n',' '.$error['error']);
}
else
{
    //if data has been uploaded successfully get the newly uploaded file and process
    //this is the data for the newly uploaded file
    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
    //resize start
    $source_path = $data['upload_data']['full_path'];
    //new path i want to put the resized image
    $target_path = './assets/uploads/thumbs';

    //just create thumbs
    $thumb['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $thumb['source_image']  = $source_path;
    $thumb['new_image'] = $target_path;
    $thumb['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
    $thumb['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
    $thumb['width']  = 100;
    $thumb['height'] = 100;
    $this->image_lib->initialize($thumb); 
    $this->image_lib->resize();
    $this->image_lib->clear();

    //resize image
    $thumb2['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $thumb2['source_image'] = $source_path;
    $thumb2['new_image']    = $data['upload_data']['file_path'];
    $thumb2['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
    $thumb2['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
    $thumb2['width'] = 200;
    $thumb2['height'] = 200;
    $this->image_lib->initialize($thumb2);
    $this->image_lib->resize();
    $this->image_lib->clear();
    //resize end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is working example...
fore more more then two images

public function add($ids1 = null) {

```
   $data['page_title']='ADD';
           if ($this->input->post()) {
   
               $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'required');
               if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
                   
               } else {
                   $cat_file = '';
                   $banner_file = '';
                   if (!empty($_FILES['image']['name'])) {
                       try {
                           $cat_file = $this->fileuploadmain($_FILES);
                       } catch (Exception $e) {
                           log_message('category images', $e->getMessage());
                       }
                   }
                   if (!empty($_FILES['banner_image']['name'])) {
                       try {
                           $banner_file = $this->fileuploadmainbanner($_FILES);
                       } catch (Exception $e) {
                           log_message('banner image category error', $e->getMessage());
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
   
           $this->maintheme('add', $data);
       }
   
   
       public function fileuploadmain($filpost) {
           $path = FCPATH . 'assets/category';
           if (!file_exists($path)) {
               mkdir($path, 0777, true);
           }
           $config['upload_path'] = $path;
           $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|jpeg|JPG';
           $config['max_size'] = 5000;
           $config['min_width'] = 400;
           $config['min_height'] = 300;
   
           $this->load->library('upload', $config);
           if (!$this->upload->do_upload('image')) {
               $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="error">', '</p>');
               $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
               $this->session->set_flashdata('error', $this->upload->display_errors());
               $this->form_validation->set_rules('file', 'File', 'required');
               return false;
           } else {
               $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
               $file_name = $upload_data['file_name'];
               $thumrest = $this->image_thumb($config['upload_path'], $file_name);
               if ($thumrest) {
                   return $file_name;
               } else {
                   return FALSE;
               }
           }
       }
   
       public function fileuploadmainbanner($filpost) {
           $path = FCPATH . 'assets/category/banner';
           if (!file_exists($path)) {
               mkdir($path, 0777, true);
           }
           $config1['upload_path'] = $path;
           $config1['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|jpeg|JPG';
           $config1['max_size'] = 5000;
   
           $this->load->library('upload', $config1);
           // here is the most important line
           $this->upload->initialize($config1);
           if (!$this->upload->do_upload('banner_image')) {
               $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="error">', '</p>');
               $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
               $this->session->set_flashdata('error', $this->upload->display_errors());
               $this->form_validation->set_rules('banner_image', 'File', 'required');
               return false;
           } else {
               $upload_data1 = $this->upload->data();
               $file_name1 = $upload_data1['file_name'];
               $thumrest1 = $this->image_thumb($config1['upload_path'], $file_name1);
               if ($thumrest1) {
                   return $file_name1;
               } else {
                   return FALSE;
               }
           }
       }
   
       public function image_thumb($folder_name, $image_name) {
           $origin_folder = $folder_name;
           $width = 200;
           $height = 200;
           $folder_name = $folder_name . '/thumbs';
           if (file_exists($folder_name) == false) {
               mkdir($folder_name, 0777);
           }
           // Path to image thumbnail
           $image_thumb = dirname($folder_name . '/' . $image_name) . '/' . $image_name;
           if (!file_exists($image_thumb)) {
               // LOAD LIBRARY
               $this->load->library('image_lib');
               // CONFIGURE IMAGE LIBRARY
               $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
               $config['source_image'] = $origin_folder . '/' . $image_name;
               $config['new_image'] = $image_thumb;
               $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
               $config['height'] = $height;
               $config['width'] = $width;
               $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
               $this->image_lib->resize();
               $this->image_lib->clear();
               return true;
           }
       }
   
   }
```